# jQuery not executing onClick for a class of buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Javascript:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){//So far AJAX isn't asyncn.
            $(".acceptorbutton").on('click', function(){
                    var whichClicked = this.attr('name');
                    var cat = parseInt(whichClicked, 10);
                    alert("this text is not appearing");
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"getuser.php",
                        data: {friendadd : cat},
                        success: function(){
                            alert("Ajax success");
                        }
                    })
            })
        });
    </script>
```

PHP and HTML Form: It is looping through for every user that the search result turns up. Next to each user is an input button that onClick should call getuser.php. The Input buttons are identical except for they're names. On the click, the jQuery should execute yet it does not detect it.

```
            <form id="friendadd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
        for($i=0; $i<$ctk->rowCount(); $i++){
            echo "<img src='".$ctk_values[$i][6]."' alt='Blank' style='width:64px;height:64px'>";//PP, Later add clickable profile
            echo "<th rowspan='3'>Attributes</th>";
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][0]."</tr>";//UN
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][1]."</tr>";//UL
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][5]."</tr>";//UA
            echo "YOYOYOO".$ctk_values[$i][4];
            $GlobalAcceptorId=$ctk_values[$i][4];
    ?>

    <div id="dom-target" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <?php
            echo $GlobalAcceptorId;
        ?>
    </div>
                <input class="acceptorbutton" type="button" name="<?php echo $ctk_values[$i][4];?>"><br>
    <?php   
        }//Ends for loop
    ?>
            </form>     
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

What I've tried so far: the alert box isn't appearing. I've tried changing the form button type to submit and made the Javascript `$(".acceptorbutton").submit(function(){....`

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if you need more information but so far I don't think I'm missing any critical data.

Comment: What sort of debugging have you done other than "it isn't working"?  Is the click handler being invoked at all?  Is the AJAX request being made?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors in the browser's JavaScript console?  Any errors in the PHP logs?  Where specifically does this fail?

Comment: @David So I think the click handler is not being invoked at all and the AJAX request is not occuring. In fact the page does not refresh and that little alert("this text is not appearing"); is not appearing. I've tried using firebug which I got today and I see the attributes alright I guess. The php should be alright, nothing in the error log. Thanks!

Comment: What does the HTML look like when you try to attach the click handler to the button?  Does that first jQuery selector find any elements with the given class at that time?  I'm unable to replicate the problem.

Comment: Previously I had the Ajax call working using only one button instead of a class of buttons but I saw someone on stackexchange use the .on('click', function()   let me see if I can pull it up.

Comment: The button is blank and when you click on it the page does not refresh. I feel like the error must either be with     

$(".acceptorbutton").on('click', function(){

or the button <input class="acceptorbutton" type="button" name="<?php echo $ctk_values[$i][4];?>"><br>

Comment: Well, the page *shouldn't* refresh if you're using AJAX.  Don't just look at the PHP code which *generates* the HTML, look at the *actual* HTML.  That's what the JavaScript sees.  So if the JavaScript isn't working as expected then you need to debug it.

Comment: @David Ok first off so sorry for my stupidity after poking around with the debugger it turns out that the function call _does work_ if I change it to `$(".acceptorbutton").click( blahandler...` The issue is with this devil `var whichClicked = this.attr('name');` I have no idea why but it kills the command from going farther. Thanks so much for your help so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error and finally got it to work! Hopefully others who have struggled with this will find this helpful. My error was that this.attr('name'); was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 whereas I'm using jQuery 2.1. The error was not with the callback at all rather it just completely like shut down and caught on fire when it saw that, not even allowing alert() to go through. Instead, use $(this).prop('name'). Thanks to all those who helped!

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){//So far AJAX isn't asyncn.
            $(".acceptorbutton").on("click", function(){
                    alert("this text is not appearing");
                    //var whichClicked = this.attr('name');
                    //var cat = parseInt(whichClicked, 10);
                    var cat = parseInt($(this).prop('name'), 10);
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"getuser.php",
                        data: {friendadd : cat},
                        success: function(){
                            alert("Ajax success");
                        }
                    });//Add data: and success:function
            })
        });
    </script>
```